# Creating bootable USB Yosemite on High Sierra for 2007 17" but hangs on copying install files to disk for 1 hour

Tags: terminal, usb, startup

I recently bought a 2007 MBP to fix. I put an HDD in and tried Internet Recovery but that did not work. So, I tried a USB stick but it hangs on "Copying installer files to disk".

[image: Screenshot of command-line output showing the installation process]

I have tried formatting as macOS because it was NTFS but still hangs.

Comment: I suppose your problem would depend on the model/year Mac being used, the type/speed/size of the flash drive, how you acquired Yosemite and the version/age of the acquired Yosemite. None of this is in your question. All of the 2007 Macs are to old to boot from Internet Recovery. Is there a reason you are not using El Capitan? I believe El Capitan may be the last version of OS X available for your 2007 Mac.

Comment: Here are some links you may find useful: [How to get old versions of macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683) and [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372). I realize you probably already know of these links, but perhaps others do not.